# Use Mono Result in Flux

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

**PROBLEM** Method needs to wait for Mono operation result, use it in Flux operation and return Flux.

```
public Flux<My> getMy() {
  Mono<ZonedDateTime> dateTimeMono = getDateTime();

  Flux<My> mies = reactiveMongoTemplate.find(
        new Query(Criteria.where("dateTime").gt(dateTimeMono)),
        My.class,
        collectionName);

  return mies;
}
```

**RESEARCH**
I expect that `dateTimeMono` stream is subscribed and terminated by Mongo reactive driver, so I don't subscribe. If I use `Mono.zip` I get Mono<Flux> as return type.

**TASKS**
How to wait for `dateTimeMono` value, use it in Flux operation and get Flux out of it?

Comment: getDateTime().flatMapMany(date -> reactiveMongoTemplate.find(new Query(Criteria.where("dateTime").gt(date)),My.class,collectionName))

Comment: The question is why you want to do that? Mono always returns zero or one item.

Comment: Yes, `flatMapMany` does the trick. Thanks a lot. Don't you want to post an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [flaMapMany](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#flatMapMany-java.util.function.Function-):

```java
public Flux<My> getMy() {
    return getDateTime().flatMapMany(date -> reactiveMongoTemplate.find(new Query(Criteria.where("dateTime").gt(date)),My.class,collectionName));
}
```